# Has a Grid background always been IsHitTestVisible="True"?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Suppose you have a Grid control filling the entire page.
On top of that Grid, you have another Grid filling the entire page.
Suppose both Grids are divided into 3x3 grids, with a Button in Row="1" Col="1" on both Grids.  The sizing of the grid columns and rows is such that the two buttons are not overlapping.

The result is that the bottom button cannot be clicked because the top Grid is blocking it.

If you set the top Grid to IsHitTestVisible="False", the bottom Button can now be pressed, but the top Button cannot.

Has it always been this way?  I was sure that I've used overlapping grids like this before and still had access to both Buttons.

(and yes, I know there are other ways to do this, but the scenario is just set that way to ask the question.)

```
            <Grid Background="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="True"
                  Width="1200" Height="800">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="600*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="400*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="400*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="400*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Bottom Grid" Background="Green"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Background="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="True"
                  Width="1200" Height="800">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="400*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="400*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="600*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Top Grid" Background="Red"/>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: Yep. Hittest is related to the order in your visualtree. When you set the top of your grid a background. It will block your bottom grid. I think you can close your thread by mark the answer so that others may also be able to benefit from your answer. At least that "Transparent" is very useful to others.

Comment: Thanks Barry.  I don't understand why setting to Transparent creates the blocking that it does.  I'm also not sure why the visual tree can't determine if IsHitTestVisible changes on the visual tree.  If it could, you could easily open holes on a Panel to let some pointer actions through and block the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the reason.

This has been driving me nuts all day.  The offending bit of code is:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent"
```

Setting the background to anything, including Transparent, prevents the click from passing through to the back.